# Sort list of ordereddict of tuples by second key in first tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, ordereddictionary

I have an list of ordereddict of tuples

```
[
    OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 5), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 6), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 8), ('info', 'info_data')])
]
```

It is possible to sort by `'id'` it and receive next list or ordereddict

```
[
    OrderedDict([('id', 5), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 6), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('info', 'info_data')]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 8), ('info', 'info_data')])
]
```

Comment: You don't have tuples. That's just the standard display for `OrderedDict` objects, which allows you to easily re-create the same values. You can sort these exactly the same way you'd sort a list of regular dictionaries.

Comment: As a new list: `sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['id'])`

Comment: I tried your version have  error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Then [edit] your question with a [mcve]. I just tried it with the example given here and it works just fine.

Comment: (so `from collections import OrderedDict`, then `list_to_be_sorted = ...` where `...` is the first code block shown here, then `sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['id'])`, produces the desired output).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/ccde7384ab87e670180e064aff5edef3